# Visualforce page to show particular record for specified users

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a code to the visualforce page where it shows a specific record for specified user. This code is a IF-ELSE scenario assuming there are two specified users nothing more. However, I would like to specify 10 different users for different records. Could anyone help me with that please?

Exisitng code

```
/************** Visualforce page *****************/
<apex:page controller="myClass" action="{!redirect}" >

</apex:page>


 /************* Controller ***********************/
public with sharing class myClass{
public string uId;

public myClass(){
    uId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
}

public pageReference redirect(){
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('URL1');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    if(uId == 'firstOption'){
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }else{
        pageRef = new PageReference('URL2');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have multiple Users accessing the page, then you can create a [Hierarchy Custom Setting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) to store a URL for each User.  This way you have a configurable way to maintain your list without having to update/redeploy code.

Start by creating a Custom Setting, for this example we'll call it "User Redirect"(`User_Redirect__c`), and make it a Hierarchy type.  Give it a custom Text field called "Redirect URL"(`Redirect_Url__c`).

Once done click the Manage button and you can then add individual records for Users (and/or Profiles).  Make sure to create a default org-wide record too as a catch all.

Now, in your controller you simply need to reference your custom setting.

```
//the system will automatically grab the record for the user if one exists, 
//else a for their profile if a record exists, else the org-default
String url = User_Redirect__c.getInstance().Redirect_Url__c;
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url);
//this is implied if redirecting to a different url. you only ever need to set 
//this if you are refreshing the current page and want to reset the state
//pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;
```